# Not able to push on mongoose array of element type ObjectId

Tags: express

I am new to express js. I have made a schema named User and it has an array field named "friends" and it has elements of type ObjectId. The Schema is shown below:

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        firstName: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        lastName: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        friends : [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
        joined: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        }
    }
)
```

I am trying to push elements of type ObjectId but it is not pushing.Below is the code I have written for pushing the element.

```
router.post('/add-friend', (req, res) => {
    User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: "604498643b130c1384e7954b" }, {
        $push: {
            friends: "60278faacf27cf0cc494d806"
        }
    }
    )
    res.send("Friend Added to friend list")
})
```

The number which I am pushing is the ObjectId of an already existing Model.I am accessing the model with its id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Friend id should be a `Schema.Types.ObjectId`.

Convert friend id string to `ObjectId` before update to User document:

```
const {ObjectID} = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
...
  User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: "604498643b130c1384e7954b" },
    {
      $push: {
        friends: ObjectID("60278faacf27cf0cc494d806"), // convert to ObjectId
      }
    },
  )
```